# python selenium : empty list is output as a crawling result

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping, webdriverwait

Here is my code.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

url_list = []
content_list = ""
text = "b%C3%A1nh%20crown"

url_maxpage = "https://shopee.vn/search?brands=3372239&keyword=" + text + "&noCorrection=true&page=0"
driver.get(url_maxpage)

by = webdriver.common.by.By

max_page = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='shopee-mini-page-controller__total')
num=int(max_page[0].text)

for i in range(num):  # Crawl from 1 to max page
    url = "https://shopee.vn/search?brands=3372239&keyword=" + text + "&noCorrection=true&page=" + str(i)
    driver.get(url)
    by = webdriver.common.by.By
    
    time.sleep(0.5)
    
    div_href = driver.find_elements(by.CLASS_NAME, "col-xs-2-4")
    hlink = []
    for i in range(int(len(div_href))):
        hlink_list = div_href[i].find_elements(by.TAG_NAME, "a")[0].get_attribute('href')
        hlink.append(hlink_list)

    
# Remove duplicates in list
my_list = hlink
my_set = set(my_list) 
my_list = list(my_set)
```

```
output : []
```

Using the code above, I want to traverse the page and crawl the links for each product.
But I don't know why it outputs an empty list.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

I modified the for statement as follows, but only 15 are output.

```
for i in range(num):  # Crawl from 1 to max page
    url = "https://shopee.vn/search?brands=3372239&keyword=" + text + "&noCorrection=true&page=" + str(i)
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    
    SCROLL_PAUSE_SEC = 10

    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_SEC)

        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
    
    hlink = []
    elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".col-xs-2-4 a")))
    
    for element in elements:
        hlink_list = element.get_attribute('href')
        hlink.append(hlink_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for elements to be loaded.
This will give you first 15 hrefs on the page.
To get all the 60 you will need to scroll the page since only 15 elements are initially loaded.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)

url = 'https://shopee.vn/search?brands=3372239&keyword=b%C3%A1nh%20crown&noCorrection=true&page=0e'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
hlink = []
elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".col-xs-2-4 a")))
for element in elements:
    hlink_list = element.get_attribute('href')
    hlink.append(hlink_list)
```

Comment: thank you!!!  I added the code for scrolling above the for statement, but still only 15 are output. Could you please take a look at the edited question?